# Why changing value of SO_RCVBUF doesn't work?

Tags: c, sockets, buffer, setsockopt

I'm making a program which create a RAW socket in order to read all traffic. Between the call of socket() and recvfrom() (last one is in a loop to get out all packets from buffer) I wait 5s.

When I run the program, I send about 200 packets with hping3 command in « faster mode » (to fill in the buffer fastly) to my program. As soon as 5s are elapsed, my program extract about 150 packets from the buffer.

I try to change the size of the receive buffer to get better result:

```
int a = 65535;
if ( (setsockopt(sockfd, 0, SO_RCVBUF, &a ,sizeof(int)) ) < 0 )
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error setting sock opts..\n");
}
```

However, whatever is the value of « a », 1 or 10000000, it seems nothing changes, I still get ~150 packets from the buffer.

What's the problem?

Edit: Value of « a » is verified with a `getsockopt` call.

Comment: Can you show us more code, including relevant calls to `socket()` etc.? Letting us know your operating system might help too.

Comment: Sure, I run this program under Linux 3.2 64bits.  The call to `socket()` : `sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `level` argument to `setsockopt` should be `SOL_SOCKET`, not `0`:

```
int a = 65535;
if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, &a, sizeof(int)) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error setting socket opts: %s\n", strerror(errno));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works well the value changes now. However the limit of receive buffer is 262142 and if a packet is 50 bytes sized then there should be about 5200 packets in memory and not only 150?

Comment: Note that the buffer size has an upper limit defined by `/proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max`. For an even larger buffer you either need to change this global limit or as a a privileged process (CAP_NET_ADMIN) you can use `SO_RCVBUFFORCE` instead of `SO_RCVBUF` to ignore the `rmem_max` limit.

Answer (score 19):

You may also be limited by the OS, if it still doesn't seem to be working.  Check the values in:

```
/proc/sys/net/core/rmem_default
/proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max
```

If it's TCP as you say in your example, and not actually a raw socket, you can also check the values in:

```
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_mem
```

If you run cat on these files they'll show you the current settings.  To change them permanently, use sysctl.  It's a good idea to write these settings down before you start changing things.  Here's a great tutorial on making those changes: http://fasterdata.es.net/fasterdata/host-tuning/linux/.

Comment: Thank you too, I've increased the rmem_max value and it works very well I can get all packets.

Comment: You have any idea about windows, where we can check this values?

Comment: As a a privileged process (CAP_NET_ADMIN) you can use `SO_RCVBUFFORCE` instead of `SO_RCVBUF` to ignore the `rmem_max` limit.