# getsockopt() returns a value twice the value that was previously set by setsockopt()

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

I am attempting to increase the `SO_RCVBUF` for a raw socket I am using to interact with a linux device driver. The default `rmem_default/rmem_max` are both too small, 163840. Therefore I am using the following [stack overflow question/answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063497/why-changing-value-of-so-rcvbuf-doesnt-work) to help me. Everything is working, or least it looks like it. However, when I get the value I set for the `SO_RCVBUF` it returns the value I set * 2? Anyone know why that is?

```
int recv_val = SOCK_RCV_BUF_MAX; socklen_t size = sizeof(recv_val);

if(setsockopt(sock_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, &recv_val, size) < 0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error setsockopt(SO_RCVBUF): %s\n", strerror(errno));
}
else
    printf("Set the SO_RCVBUF to %d\n", recv_val);

recv_val = 0;

if (getsockopt(sock_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, &recv_val, &size) < 0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error getsockopt(SO_RCVBUF): %s\n", strerror(errno));
}
else if(recv_val == SOCK_RCV_BUF_MAX)
{
    printf("Successfully set the buffer max to %d\n", SOCK_RCV_BUF_MAX);
}
else
    printf("Failed to set the buffer to max (%d), val = %d\n", SOCK_RCV_BUF_MAX, recv_val);
```

Output

```
Set the SO_RCVBUF to 64000000
Failed to set the buffer to max (64000000), val = 128000000
```

Changing to `recv_val = SOCK_RCV_BUF_MAX/2` outputs

```
Set the SO_RCVBUF to 32000000
Successfully set the buffer max to 64000000
```

If I don't set the value using setsockopt() and call getsockopt() for my socket I get the correct default value

```
Failed to set the buffer to max (64000000), val = 163840
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]?

Comment: I set up my socket as `socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL));` along with other calls that pertain to my device driver setsockopt(SO_BINDTODEVICE), but other than that its a normal raw socket.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value you give to `setsockopt(SO_RCVBUF)` is only a **hint**, not an absolute.  The socket provider is allowed to use a different value if it wants to. What you get back from `getsockopt(SO_RCVBUF)` is the *actual* value used.

What you are seeing happen is actually **documented behavior**:

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html

> SO_RCVBUF
>   Sets or gets the maximum socket receive buffer in bytes.  **The kernel doubles this value (to allow space for bookkeeping overhead) when it is set using [`setsockopt(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setsockopt.2.html), and this doubled value is returned by [`getsockopt(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getsockopt.2.html)**.  The default value is set by the `/proc/sys/net/core/rmem_default` file, and the maximum allowed value is set by the `/proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max` file. The minimum (doubled) value for this option is 256.

Comment: I set the rmem_max to 64000000, I find it unsettling that it would then allow for my socket to have twice that max value? I guess the max is a loose guideline and not strictly enforced? Thanks for this, I was looking at http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setsockopt.2.html and didn't search enough. Thank you!