# java Datagram Socket not processing data fast enough

Tags: java, sockets, networking, udp

I am testing data transfer using UDP on my computer (localhost). On the sending end, there is a simple while loop that sends packets of 512 bytes. On the receiving end there is a thread that continuously reads form the socket and prints the number of packets it had read so far.

Sending end:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
    byte[] data = new byte[512];
    try {
        client.socket.send(new DatagramPacket(data, 0, data.length, InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 4337));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Receiving end:

```
while (true) {
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(input_buffer, input_buffer.length);
    try {
        socket.receive(packet);
        System.out.println("counter = " + l++);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
... 
counter = 1213
counter = 1214
counter = 1215
counter = 1216
counter = 1217
```

The sender sent 5000 packets, but the receiver received only 1217.

The reason I know the issue lies in the processing speed in the receiving end is that the problem vanishes if I wait a millisecond between sending each packet by adding the line `Thread.sleep(1);`

Is there any way of solving this problem without adding a delay?

Comment: @JanezKuhar Yeah but I am reading the packets as fast as possible, not even inspecting the data inside them or doing any memcpy. It would be very surprising if the socket didn't have some kind of a buffer for cases where two packets arrive at the same time.

Comment: Taking a closer look at [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/71412), I think you might be interested in setting a bigger buffer size via [`setReceiveBufferSize()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#setReceiveBufferSize(int)) and [`setSendBufferSize()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#setSendBufferSize(int)).

Comment: I just tried it but unfortunately it did not work (I set the buffer size to 5000*packet_size so there wasn't any shortage of space for sure).

Comment: I've used `socket.setReceiveBufferSize(Integer.MAX_VALUE);` on the server and it worked. It also worked using: `socket.setReceiveBufferSize(5000*512);`. Perhaps your system is a bit slower.

Comment: Could you please share your code with me? I must have done a mistake somewhere but can't seem to find it. Also, it seems to me like as long as you got enough memory the cpu speed doesn't matter as much. Thank you for helping me with this.

Comment: I meant the RAM/cache/DISK speed. Here's my code: https://gist.github.com/Glusk/c93d0b470a0a247aead7e133af00e303

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215447/discussion-between-janez-kuhar-and-roy-varon).

Comment: You could speed up the sending too, by not calling `InetAddress.getByName()`every time around the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Why changing value of SO_RCVBUF doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063497/why-changing-value-of-so-rcvbuf-doesnt-work/10063799#10063799)

This post shows how to find the maximum receiver buffer size for sockets on linux. In my case the limit was too low therefore some of the packets were discarded.

After further testing, I found that routing the packets through the internet instead of sending them to localhost introduces enough of a delay such that all the packets get to be processed.